# UI-Grid 3.1.1 cell editing boolean not responding to spacebar

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've had the grid setup for a bit, not sure what I did, but the ability to check the box in the cell editing has stopped working but only on checkboxes.  I used Brian Hahn's method of building out select boxes and the like. I've tried this again inside a plnkr and it seems to work fine in there.

Below are my gridOptions

```
rowHeight: 38,
enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
enableFiltering: true,
rowEditWaitInterval: -1,
columnDefs: [
{
    name: 'hqLocation',
    displayName: 'HQ',
    type: 'boolean',
    minWidth: 100
}]
```

and the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div ui-grid="gridOptions"
         class="grid"
         style="{{gridHeight()}}"
         ui-grid-pinning
         ui-grid-edit
         ui-grid-row-edit
         ui-grid-resize-columns
         ui-grid-cellNav></div>
</div>
```

So the behavior is that it seems that it enters the cell editor, but I can't click on it (it flips between the edit and non-edit) or if I press the spacebar nothing changes.

Comment: Please provide a demo such as plunker to help with troubleshooting this.

Comment: Well dangit, I can't seem to get it to do it in plnkr.  I think it might be something else that someone else did. Not sure whats interrupting it, but I'm going to have to track this one down on my own.

Comment: :( good luck. I would start by trying to remove anything that you didn't have in the plunker, and then adding back slowly.